# Unable to print data to html page from mysql query in flask python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, html-table

This is my app.py file mysql query retrives to data normally

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
    form = GenreForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
      genre = request.form['genre']
      cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
      result = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM music_src WHERE type_of_music = %s"""(genre,))
    if result > 0:
      data = cur.fetchone()
    else:
      return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
      cur.close()
return redirect(url_for('search', data=data))
```

Here is my search.html code

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block body %}
<table border="1" bordercolor="white" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="35" style="font-family:Georgia, Garamond, Serif;color:white;font-style:italic;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Type_of_music</th>     
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in data %} 
            <tr>
                <td>{row[0]}</td>
                <td>{row[1]}</td>
                <td>{row[2]}</td>   
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}       
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

When i debugged mysql query passes data like below. Is this the reason why its not printing? If so how can i print this in table format of ID Title and Type_of_music

```
data={'id':+28,+'title':+'Once+upon+a+time+&ndash;+James+Bond',+'type_of_music':+'sad'}
```

Answer (score 0):

data = cur.fetchone()
this only return 1 which mean you do not have to loop
try -> delete "{% for row in data %} " ?

Comment: Even cur.fetchall() doesn't print in the html. So I tried to replace it with cur.fetchone() to debug it, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the above problem. Need to add this session['data']=data

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
    form = GenreForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
      genre = request.form['genre']
      cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
      result = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM music_src WHERE type_of_music = %s"""(genre,))
    if result > 0:
      data = cur.fetchall()
      **session['data'] = data**
    return redirect(url_for('search', data=data))
    else:
      return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
      cur.close()
return redirect(url_for('search', data=data))
```